# How to stop drawing when y=0

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

For a real time pitch detection graph, I am using `GraphView` to plot pitch against time. Pitch is on Y-axis and time on X-axis:

```
public void generateData(float[] pitch, double rms) {
    double y=0;
    double time = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;

    for (int i = 0; i < pitch.length; i += 1000) {
        y = (double) pitch[i];
        Log.d("Pitch", y + "");

            if (y!=0) {
            //if (rms >= 2) {
            series.appendData(new DataPoint(time, y), true, 40);

            } 
    }
}
```

[image: Pitch vs time]

I don't want the blue line to fall to zero or start from zero. When the sound stops, the lines should stop there and then when the sound begins again, the graph should begin the pitch where the sound started.

Please help?

Comment: I can't see the image, did u upload it correctly?

Comment: (without I would have seen the image) Did u tried to change the condition to sg like if (y>= 0.01)? In my oppinion it is possible that the value of y becomes very low, but not exactly zero. Is it possible?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50058001/edit) your post to display the image correctly. hint : change `[Pitch vs time][2]` by `![Pitch vs time][1]`

Comment: Not able to load image as it says my posts are not yet ten in numbers. Will try again.

Comment: So did u tried to set the condition to if (y>= 0.01)? Or could you print the values of y also?

Comment: Doesn't work. It only connects from last point if sound begins again. It draws a long line from last point.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem than, please edit your question. What would you like to achieve? What are the values of y? You don't even have axis labels....

Comment: Its not so difficult to understand. I had just commented out the axis labels, which run from 0 to 700. What I want to achieve is quite clear: when the sound begins, the blue line should not begin from 0 and draw to the first value in the pitch array, the same way with end - it should not draw from the last value to 0. It should stop where the last value stops and begin with the first value. The image is so clear, isnt it - how the blue line raises in the beginning and falls in the end. Pl give some constructive help.

Comment: "if(y>=0.01)" does not work because it stops the graph from scrolling when the sound stops. And, when the sound begins, it takes from the last drawn point and draws a long line before reacting to the sound.

Comment: Than probably have the problem with the x axis, don't you? Why is the x constant anyway? it should be a counter I think.

Comment: Did u solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I replied with thanks but the mods deleted the posts. Problem solved after I changed the constant and made it variable. y>=0.01 was the solution.